# Calculated Column with IF ISBLANK, else if "ABC", then return "XYX"

Tags: column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

If `[OH:Subsample ID]` is blank, OR if it contains "ABC", then the calculated field should return result "XYZ".

No idea how to put that into syntax.

I can get two separate lines, but can't get them combined into one command line:

```
=IF([OH:Subsample ID]"Header Line","Audit")


=IF(ISBLANK([OH:Subsample ID]),"Audit")
```

Comment: Do you want the exact match of "ABC" or the field value `contains` substring "ABC" inside it's value?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using OR is as follows:

```
=IF(OR([Column1]>[Column2], [Column1]<[Column3]), "OK", "Not OK")
```

So try:

```
 =IF(OR([OH:Subsample ID]="ABC", ISBLANK([OH:Subsample ID])),"Audit")
```

The sample above came from [this doc](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-common-formulas-in-SharePoint-Lists-D81F5F21-2B4E-45CE-B170-BF7EBF6988B3), which has other samples as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OR** function to build such formula. Try using below formula:

```
=IF(OR([OH:Subsample ID]="ABC", ISBLANK([OH:Subsample ID])),"XYZ", "FalseValue")
```

In this formula I have combined **IF** and **OR** functions. For detailed syntax and examples check below references.

**Reference**:

1. [OR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).